# Removing all other areas except selected areas in mapview

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-maps

Suppose I have made a diagram e.g a circle on `android mapView`. Now I want to `remove/blackout/hide` all other maps except that portion. I can zoom in out that portion too

Is this possible?

Best Regards

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have  a similar problem of make map view inside certain area.not sure it will help you or not but you can try it.

What you should do is take image of circle(**Background is Transparent**) and put your image as background in Linear layout. and inside that LinearLayout you can put map view.

your **xml** will Look like below.

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/Circle_back" >

            <com.google.android.maps.MapView
                android:id="@+id/whereami_mapview"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:apiKey="YOUR API KEY"
                android:clickable="true" />
        </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

i have to view it inside rectangle box. below is the similar screen shot you will get while running. you d'nt need to hide rest of the part of Map.

hope it will help some how what are you looking for.
[image]

Comment: thats a great trick, however check my edit, thats what i want :)

Comment: ohh..if you are fine with my opinion then you can make the same image what you want by making the image border cracked(Of Course with some what color)? then at run time i think it will look like your Screenshot.

Comment: actually i want to draw that red line with touch of hand ofc and then some button to separate that area from whole map and blackend whole map etc

Answer (score 0):

Make a trick

Zoom will work in your case. Set zoom level and

Use `android:clickable="false"` in your layout file.

;)

Comment: I Want to hide all other map areas :) or make them appear shadowed etc